# Unity - Player is only detected in trigger when moving

Tags: c#, triggers, collision-detection, unity-game-engine

In my game I have a switch. The switch has a trigger on it to detect when the player is touching is so that he/she can flick it my pressing 'E'.

The weird part is I can only trigger the switch when the player is moving, I am using addforce for movement.

Below is the code for my player and my switch. I have also attached my project folder so that if someone is willing to take the time and try it they can. The reproduction rate is 100% of the time for me.

Obviously this is not the intended result, the player should be able to activate the switch even if they are standing still.

PLAYERMOVEMENT.CS:

```
using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

     private Rigidbody2D R2Dplayer;
     private bool grounded = true;
     [SerializeField] private Animator anim;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {
         R2Dplayer = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {
         anim.SetFloat("speed", Mathf.Abs(R2Dplayer.velocity.x));
         if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
             if(grounded == true) {
                 R2Dplayer.AddForce (new Vector2(0,7.5f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
             }
         }
         if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
             R2Dplayer.AddForce (new Vector2(-0.2f,0), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
             if (R2Dplayer.transform.rotation == new Quaternion (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)) {
                 R2Dplayer.transform.Rotate (0, 180, 0);
             }
         }
         if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)) {

         }
         if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
             R2Dplayer.AddForce (new Vector2(0.2f,0), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
             if (R2Dplayer.transform.rotation == new Quaternion (0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)) {
                 R2Dplayer.transform.Rotate (0, 180, 0);
             }
         }
     }

     void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D c) {
         if(c.tag == "JumpTrigger") {
             grounded = true;
         }
     }

     void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D c) {
         if(c.tag == "JumpTrigger") {
             grounded = false;
         }
     }
 }
```

SWITCH.CS:

```
using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class Switch : MonoBehaviour {

     [SerializeField] public bool switchPressed = false;
     private SpriteRenderer sr;
     [SerializeField] private Sprite on, off;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {
         sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {

     }

     void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D c) {
         if(c.tag == "Player") {
             if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) {
                 if(switchPressed == false) {
                     sr.sprite = on;
                     switchPressed = true;
                 }
                 else if(switchPressed == true) {
                     sr.sprite = off;
                     switchPressed = false;
                 }

             }
         }
     }
 }
```

ZIP of my project that can be downloaded from dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/85anfa4287mciiy/Final.zip?dl=0

Comment: Have you tried using the Boolean-based system you used with JumpTriggers to store if the player is colliding with a trigger, and then moving the `if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))` block to update (with the added condition having a collision with the player stored?

Comment: I think you can check the physics collision and trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?
[image]
**Static collider/Rigidbody Collider** can not trig another static collider/rigidbody/kinematic rb

Hope it will help.